# why sdwebimage can't download image while my api works fine with https?

Tags: ios, https, sdwebimage, tls1.2, app-transport-security

I check my server with :

```
nscurl --verbose --ats-diagnostics https://xxx
```

It shows my server only supports TLSV1.0, but my API works fine and I can get my JSON data with it .

When I get my image URL with JSON data to load my image by `SDWebImage`,it shows

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)
```

So, I'm confused, 
If my server doesn't support the minimum TLS version, why does my API work?
Otherwise, if my server is ok, why does XCode show that `kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL` wrong?

My image URL is also similar:

```
https://xxx.xxxxx.xxx/xxx.jpg
```

Comment: How is your API call made? NSURLConnection?

Answer (score -2):

In the info.plist of your project, you need to add a key "Add Transport Security Settings" which is a dictionary and contains a variable "Allow Arbitrary Loads" which is boolean and is set to true.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict> 
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

[image: info.plist]

Comment: i need too use https but not shut down it..  thx anyway.. :-D

Comment: oh once I faced a similar kind of issue Http load failed and this worked but yeah that was for HTTP endpoint my bad i haven't gone through the whole question

Comment: You shouldn't recommend this solution at this point without providing an explanation to the poster that this change is not recommended and will require justification to make it through the App Store submit process. Also, a better solution would be to add a domain exception that only lowers the TLS version. The blanket disabling of ATS is in general a bad idea unless your app allows the user to connect to servers of their own choosing that the developer doesn't know ahead of time.